# Webview did finish load for frame not called for HTML5 video players

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

I am using WebView to play few flash videos, but in some cases the URL received can be a MP4 file. In this case it will play using inbuilt HTML5 player. I need to know when webpage has finished loading as I need to inject Javascript. But it wont get called if its a HTML5 player.

I have set the frameload & resource load delegates and I can see that its getting called if its any other web page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding an observer for your webview?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_webViewProgressFinished:) name:WebViewProgressFinishedNotification object:webView];
```

And then you can call your javascript code inside:

```
- (void)_webViewProgressFinished:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[webView windowScriptObject] callWebScriptMethod:@"YourJavascriptMethod" withArguments:
 [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil]];
}
```

Comment: For HTML5 videos Dom load never gets called until the Video has finished playing, because Video will be still buffering initially.